# Video stream from Android phone to laptop over the internet

Tags: applications, video, streaming, video-calling

I would like to transfer a video stream coming from my Android device to a remote PC through the internet. I want to connect to the Android device from my PC to see what is showing on its camera.

I tried TeamViewer but it does not allow the user to access a mobile phone from a PC.

I tried Skype & Tango (Video call) but they do not automatically answer calls.

I am struggling to find a solution. Is there any?

Comment: Have you searched Google Play Store? Use "IP Camera" as search string. You will see apps to control IP camera through your phone, which is not what you want. You will also see apps to turn your phone as IP camera. This is what you want. Next, few of these apps work with USN only, WiFi only.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is: [WebCam Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.andhat.WebCamFree) consists of an app for your Android device, plus a server component to be put on your computer. From the apps description, this could do what you want (didn't try it myself, but it's certainly worth a look). I linked the free version; a paid version is available for about 1.50 Euro.

If that doesn't do (or you don't like the idea of a PC component), you might give a try to [Cloud Spy Cam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.simplylogic.android.cloudcam) (it also has a demo available on the play store). Sounds even more promising (I'd say this is exactly what you're looking for).

But since all good things are three, a third option is [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&feature=related_apps), which "Turns your phone into a network camera with multiple viewing options."

So now, happy play!

Comment: The first app streams video from PC to Phone not in the opposite way which I want. The second one is not free. The third one requires a router to upload the video to the internet.My android phone connects to the internet using 3G Network. I am looking for a solution using my 3G network

Answer (score 0):

Look for VLC Player on Google Play. Then, install VLC your PC, and read [this article](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/android/how-to-stream-video-from-your-android-device-to-a-pc-and-vice-versa/239532).

Comment: Can you put a summary of the contents of ***this article*** you have mentioned?